# Ubuntu 16.10 makes wifi ununsable for other devices

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm running 16.10 on my laptop and sometimes WIFI just works fine on my laptop as well as Android devices. Othertimes the laptop get's a very slow connection/websites don't load at all. But also other devices (Android) connected to the same network don't get any speed. When I disable networking on the Ubuntu laptop the connection comes back. This conditions stays for hours or days, then resolves itself. It also repeatedly disconnects from Wifi by itself. I installed Ubuntu 16.10 new as I feared that the old install was messed up. But now 2 days later (after it worked fine) it's back. I used the WiFi of my landlord, so I don't have really access to the router. We use AT&T.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2c97]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Any explanation for this phenomena, any way to test it or look for packages that could be the culprit?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Are you using `(Automatic) DHCP` addressing in your wireless network profile, or `manual` (static) addressing? Check the IPv4 tab in the wireless profile.

Comment: It's "automatic", I didn't change it.